# How to cast a string as an array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have 5 different arrays for a bunch of excercises, like so:

```
    const oef1:Array = ["citroen","schoen","boek"];
    const oef2:Array = ["huis","muis","jas"];
    const oef3:Array = ["boek","koek","sok"];
    const oef4:Array = ["ei","bij","bot"];
    const oef5:Array = ["vier","mier","muur"];
```

Now I want to set the current game. I do this by copying the array, like so:

```
var curArr:Array;
var curExc:int = 1;
curArr = ("oef" + curExc) as Array;
```

I can't convince flash to accept the string ("oef"+curExc) as an Array.
How do I do this?

I have searched Stack Overflow extensively but I think I simply don't know the correct lingo for what I'm looking for. It's the only possible reason I can think of why I can't find the answer here because I'm sure someone must have already tried this. Apologies if this is the case, please point me to the right question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use square brackets.

```
curArr = this["oef" + curExc];
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand exactly why your solution works though. I always thought you can only use this[bla] when referring to items added to the displaylist?

Comment: That's the notation for assembling a property name from other variables. It's also often used when referring to dynamic properties just to make clear that they are dynamic as opposed to writing them out verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

```
const oef1:Array = ["citroen","schoen","boek"];
const oef2:Array = ["huis","muis","jas"];
const oef3:Array = ["boek","koek","sok"];
const oef4:Array = ["ei","bij","bot"];
const oef5:Array = ["vier","mier","muur"];

const oefArrays:Array = [oef1,oef2,oef3,oef4,oef5];


var curArr:Array;
var curExc:int = 0;
curArr = oefArrays[curExc];
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works too! I suppose now it's only a matter of personal preference which one to use. In that case I prefer the first solution, because I don't have to add yet another extra array.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a two-dimensional array, like so:

```
wrapper => [
    0 => oef1,
    1 => oef2,
    2 => oef3,
    3 => oef4,
    4 => oef5,
]
```

And just retrieve `wrapper[curExc]`.

Have a great day.

Comment: This looks like advanced array magic to me :) I have never worked with two-dimensional arrays before but I will certainly look into it, thanks!

Comment: It's the same thing that Sam suggested, only expressed in a different manner :)